# How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?

Tags: struct, clone, rust, traits, cloneable

I wrote a program that has the trait `Animal` and the struct `Dog` implementing the trait. It also has a struct `AnimalHouse` storing an animal as a trait object `Box<Animal>`.

```
trait Animal {
    fn speak(&self);
}

struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

impl Dog {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Dog {
        return Dog {
            name: name.to_string(),
        };
    }
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!{"{}: ruff, ruff!", self.name};
    }
}

struct AnimalHouse {
    animal: Box<Animal>,
}

fn main() {
    let house = AnimalHouse {
        animal: Box::new(Dog::new("Bobby")),
    };
    house.animal.speak();
}
```

It returns "Bobby: ruff, ruff!" as expected, but if I try to clone `house` the compiler returns errors:

```
fn main() {
    let house = AnimalHouse {
        animal: Box::new(Dog::new("Bobby")),
    };
    let house2 = house.clone();
    house2.animal.speak();
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for type `AnimalHouse` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:31:24
   |
23 | struct AnimalHouse {
   | ------------------ method `clone` not found for this
...
31 |     let house2 = house.clone();
   |                        ^^^^^
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `std::clone::Clone`
```

I tried to add `#[derive(Clone)]` before `struct AnimalHouse` and got another error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Animal: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:25:5
   |
25 |     animal: Box<Animal>,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `Animal`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::clone::Clone` for `std::boxed::Box<Animal>`
   = note: required by `std::clone::Clone::clone`
```

How do I make the struct `AnimalHouse` cloneable? Is it idiomatic Rust to use a trait object actively, in general?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There are a few problems.  The first is that there's nothing to require that an `Animal` also implements `Clone`.  You could fix this by changing the trait definition:

```rust
trait Animal: Clone {
    /* ... */
}
```

This would cause `Animal` to no longer be object safe, meaning that `Box<dyn Animal>` will become invalid, so that's not great.

What you *can* do is insert an additional step.  To whit (with additions from [@ChrisMorgan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-trait-object#comment48814207_30353928)).

```rust
trait Animal: AnimalClone {
    fn speak(&self);
}

// Splitting AnimalClone into its own trait allows us to provide a blanket
// implementation for all compatible types, without having to implement the
// rest of Animal.  In this case, we implement it for all types that have
// 'static lifetime (*i.e.* they don't contain non-'static pointers), and
// implement both Animal and Clone.  Don't ask me how the compiler resolves
// implementing AnimalClone for dyn Animal when Animal requires AnimalClone;
// I have *no* idea why this works.
trait AnimalClone {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Animal>;
}

impl<T> AnimalClone for T
where
    T: 'static + Animal + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn Animal> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

// We can now implement Clone manually by forwarding to clone_box.
impl Clone for Box<dyn Animal> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Animal> {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

impl Dog {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Dog {
        Dog {
            name: name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("{}: ruff, ruff!", self.name);
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct AnimalHouse {
    animal: Box<dyn Animal>,
}

fn main() {
    let house = AnimalHouse {
        animal: Box::new(Dog::new("Bobby")),
    };
    let house2 = house.clone();
    house2.animal.speak();
}
```

By introducing `clone_box`, we can get around the problems with attempting to clone a trait object.

Comment: Not sure if I should make another question or not but why does extending `Clone` mean that your trait is no longer object safe? What does that mean?

Comment: @Oli `clone` returns `Self`. This is not allowed for a trait object because the size cannot be known at compile-time.

Comment: Stupid question: How does one implement this for types with limited lifetime (non-'static)?

Comment: @soulsource: I was struggling with this too. After much research, it turns out the 'static lifetime is actually implicit for all owned types. Box<T> is always equivalent to Box<T + 'static>, since Box always owns its contents. Lifetimes only apply to references in rust.
https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html

Comment: @PeterHall how does vec succeed to implement clone while remaining sized?

Answer (score 40):

My [**`dyn-clone`**](https://github.com/dtolnay/dyn-clone) crate implements a reusable version of [DK.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object/30353928#30353928). With it you can make your original code work with a bare minimum of changes.

- One line to add `DynClone` as a supertrait of `Animal`, requiring every animal implementation to be clonable.
- One line to generate an implementation of the standard library `Clone` for `Box<dyn Animal>`.

---

```
// [dependencies]
// dyn-clone = "1.0"

use dyn_clone::{clone_trait_object, DynClone};

trait Animal: DynClone {
    fn speak(&self);
}

clone_trait_object!(Animal);

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Dog {
    name: String,
}

impl Dog {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Dog {
        Dog { name: name.to_owned() }
    }
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!{"{}: ruff, ruff!", self.name};
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct AnimalHouse {
    animal: Box<dyn Animal>,
}

fn main() {
    let house = AnimalHouse {
        animal: Box::new(Dog::new("Bobby")),
    };
    let house2 = house.clone();
    house2.animal.speak();
}
```

Answer (score 21):

**Edit (dric512)**: Slightly updating (Fixing) this answer. It answers partly the question but is still a useful answer, with limitations:

- When cloning the parent structure, the dynamic trait is not cloned, only the reference count is incremented. This cannot be used if the dynamic object needs to be duplicated.
- As a result, the trait does not need to extend `Clone` and becomes object safety.

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353928/155423) correctly answers the question about storing a boxed trait object.

Getting off topic with respect to the title, but not about the idiomatic way of using trait objects, an alternative solution could be use the `Rc` smart pointer instead of a `Box`: the trait object does not need to implement `Clone` as cloning the structure means incrementing the reference count on the object:

```
trait Animal {
    fn speak(&self);
}

...

#[derive(Clone)]
struct AnimalHouse {
    animal: Rc<dyn Animal>,
}

fn main() {
    let house = AnimalHouse { animal: Rc::new(Dog::new("Bobby")) };
    let house2 = house.clone();
    house2.animal.speak();
}
```

**Note**: `Rc<T>` is only for use in single-threaded scenarios; there's also `Arc<T>`.

Comment: I think it's important to note that this is a viable alternative *if and only if* the business logic doesn't need a true clone of the object, i.e. to reference a distinct copy of the object in memory. Rc merely clones the pointer, not the data itself.

Comment: Also worth noting that this is not acceptable if the data is ever borrowed as mutable, since you can't borrow an Rc as mutable.

Comment: Why does it not need `dyn Animal`?

Comment: I still get: the trait `X` cannot be made into an object