# Can't clone Vec<Box<Trait>> because Trait cannot be made into an object

Tags: rust, clone, trait-objects

I'm trying to clone a vector of boxed traits.
Naturally simply deriving `Clone` on all the structs that implement my trait isn't enough, because the compiler doesn't know at compile time that all the structs implementing the trait have `Clone`.

Okay, so I then tried to use `Clone` as a supertrait, but that just lead to the error in the title. I'm at a loss for solutions.

Here's the Minimal Working Implementation (or not working, since I can't clone)

```
#![allow(dead_code, unused_macros)]
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait MusicElement: Debug + Clone {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Note<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    duration: f32,
}

impl<'a> MusicElement for Note<'a> {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32 {
        self.duration
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Pause {
    duration: f32,
}

impl MusicElement for Pause {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32 {
        self.duration
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Sequence {
    elements: Vec<Box<MusicElement>>,
}

impl MusicElement for Sequence {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32 {
        self.elements.iter().map(|e| e.duration()).sum()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a4 = |dur| Box::new(Note { name: "a4", duration: dur });
    let seq = Sequence { elements: vec![a4(0.25), a4(0.25), a4(0.5)] };
    println!("{:?}", seq);
    let seq2 = seq.clone();
    println!("{:?}", seq2);
}
```

With this error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `MusicElement` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
33 |     elements: Vec<Box<MusicElement>>,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `MusicElement` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

And here's a [link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c92279dd4d034b815e815a5b0ad553aa&version=stable) for easy code running.

I've also tried to make the `elements` vector in `Sequence` a `Vec<Box<MusicElement + Clone>>`, but that didn't work either.

I haven't been able to find any useful solutions online, so here's my question: How do I make the code cloneable?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object). @Electric Coffee: does this help you?

Comment: I get an error saying `Note<'a>` doesn't satisfy the static lifetime

Comment: Why don't u use `String` as name?

Comment: Is implementing `Clone` really necessary for your business logic? This error is caused due to the Rust compiler needing to know the concrete return type of `Clone::clone` at compile time, which isn't possible with the trait object `Box<MusicElement>` (which uses dynamic dispatch). [Read more on Object-safety violation here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects)

Comment: unfortunately, yes. The Sequence struct lets me create deeply nested chains of MusicElements, which the program needs to be able to handle. For the sake of my own sanity, I'd prefer if I make a copy of one such sequence, rather than being forced to write it anew from scratch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution lies in combining the suggestions in the comments thus far - the answer in [@Lukas Kalbertodt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017987/cant-clone-vecboxtrait-because-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object/50020961#comment87052580_50017987) tells you that you must create a blanket trait implementation for all compatible (`'static + MusicElement + Clone`) types. The only subsequent step necessary for your implementation is changing the `Note.name` field's type from `&'a str` to `String`, [as metioned by @Boiethios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017987/cant-clone-vecboxtrait-because-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object/50020961#comment87057069_50017987):

```
#![allow(dead_code, unused_macros)]
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait MusicElement: MusicElementClone + Debug {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32;
}

trait MusicElementClone {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<MusicElement>;
}

impl<T: 'static + MusicElement + Clone> MusicElementClone for T {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<MusicElement> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl Clone for Box<MusicElement> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<MusicElement> {
        self.clone_box()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Note {
    name: String,
    duration: f32,
}

impl MusicElement for Note {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32 {
        self.duration
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Pause {
    duration: f32,
}

impl MusicElement for Pause {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32 {
        self.duration
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Sequence {
    elements: Vec<Box<MusicElement>>,
}

impl MusicElement for Sequence {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32 {
        self.elements.iter().map(|e| e.duration()).sum()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a4 = |dur| Box::new(Note { name: String::from("a4"), duration: dur });
    let seq = Sequence { elements: vec![a4(0.25), a4(0.25), a4(0.5)] };
    println!("{:?}", seq);
    let seq2 = seq.clone();
    println!("{:?}", seq2);
}
```

This compiles, so it should suffice!

Answer (score 4):

My [**`dyn-clone`**](https://github.com/dtolnay/dyn-clone) crate provides a reusable implementation of [jonny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017987/cant-clone-vecboxtrait-because-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object/50020961#50020961). With it you can make your original code work with a bare minimum of changes.

---

#### Before:

```
trait MusicElement: Debug + Clone {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32;
}
```

#### After:

```
use dyn_clone::DynClone;

trait MusicElement: Debug + DynClone {
    fn duration(&self) -> f32;
}

dyn_clone::clone_trait_object!(MusicElement);

// Everything else as you wrote it.
```