# How to store impl Fn in an enum type?

Tags: rust

I had a use-case where I wanted to store a function in an enum type

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum RispErr {
    Reason(String),
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum RispExp {
    Bool(bool),
    Symbol(String),
    Number(f64),
    List(Vec<RispExp>),
    Func(fn(&Vec<RispExp>) -> Result<RispExp, RispErr>),
}
```

In one case, I wanted to create a higher order function to generate these

```rust
// simplifying this for the question
// shortening this for brevity
fn make_tonicity_checker(
    tone_fn: fn(f64, f64) -> bool,
) -> impl Fn(&Vec<RispExp>) -> Result<RispExp, RispErr> {
    return move |args: &Vec<RispExp>| -> Result<RispExp, RispErr> {
        tone_fn(1.0, 2.0); // need to use this
        return Ok(RispExp::Bool(true));
    };
}
```

I come across errors though when I tried to use the higher order function

```rust
fn f() -> () {
    RispExp::Func(make_tonicity_checker(|a, b| a > b));
}
```

```
mismatched types

expected fn pointer, found opaque type

note: expected type `for<'r> fn(&'r std::vec::Vec<RispExp>) -> std::result::Result<RispExp, RispErr>`
         found type `impl for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r std::vec::Vec<RispExp>,)>`rustc(E0308)
main.rs(93, 5): expected fn pointer, found opaque type
```

I dug deeper and realized that function pointers cannot capture the environment, and hence the error. I tried

```rust
Func(Fn(&Vec<RispExp>) -> Result<RispExp, RispErr>),
```

but, realized this fails too, as it doesn't have a size known at compile time. with some googling, I found that I could potentially pass this in as a type parameter

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum RispExp<T>
where
    T: Fn(&Vec<RispExp<T>>) -> Result<RispExp<T>, RispErr>,
{
    Bool(bool),
    Symbol(String),
    Number(f64),
    List(Vec<RispExp<T>>),
    Func(T),
}
```

but then, in all places where I accept `RispExp`, I would need to provide this type parameter. That seems a bit annoying to do, because I would have to repeat `where T: Fn(&Vec<RispExp<T>>) -> Result<RispExp<T>, RispErr>,` everywhere.

I could do `Func(Box<Fn(&Vec<RispExp>) -> Result<RispExp, RispErr>>)`, but then `dyn fn` doesn't implement `Clone`.

What would you recommend I do?

Comment: I don't understand why using type parameter is tought to do but instead you can `Box` the `Fn` ->  `Func(Box<Fn(&Vec<RispExp>) -> Result<RispExp, RispErr>>),`

Comment: Thanks for the Box idea Omer. The only problem with that, is that `dyn fn` does not implement `clone`. The reason using the type parameter seemed tough to do, was because I would have to repeat that long line over and over again in a bunch of places. What would you recommend I do?

Comment: What about `Func(Rc<Fn(&Vec<RispExp>) -> Result<RispExp, RispErr>>)`? (Or `Arc<...>` if you need `RispExp` to be `Send` and/or `Sync`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save on typing, make your type parameter bound into an alias.

```rust
type RispFunc<T> = Fn(&Vec<RispExp<T>>) -> Result<RispExp<T>, RispErr>;

enum RispExp<Func: RispFunc<Func>> {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, if you use the trait object approach, you can try to implement your own `clone()` - [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object) .