# How to make a trait (and a struct implementing it) clonable?

Tags: rust

Compiling the following code, an error occurs as follows.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn T: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:21
```

Please help me to fix the code.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a55b60af1ed28002452a71b96738d3a)

```
trait T {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct S1 { val: isize, nd:B ox<dyn T> }

#[derive(Clone)]
struct S2 { val: isize }

impl T for S1 {}
impl T for S2 {}

fn main() {
   let x2 = S2 { val: 2 };
   let x1 = S1 { val: 1, nd: Box::new(x2) };
   let x1 = x1.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler tells you that trait `Clone` is not satisfied for `Box<dyn T>`.

To get around this, what you can do is:

```rust
trait T: Clone {}
```

This will force all implementors of `T` to implement `Clone` as well.

This fixed one thing, but after doing this you will see a new error disallowing you to construct a trait object.

```
error[E0038]: the trait `T` cannot be made into an object
 --> /Users/mihir/fquicktest/data/user_data/instances/so_rust_q.rs:3:21
  |
3 | struct S1{val:isize,nd:Box<dyn T>,}
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `T` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0038`.
```

**I would really suggest that you give a read to `rustc --explain E0038`. It's documented really well and will explain you the situations under which you can't make trait object.**

Futher, to solve this, you can use [dyn-clone](https://crates.io/crates/dyn-clone).

Updating you code:

```rust
use dyn_clone::DynClone;

trait T: DynClone {}
dyn_clone::clone_trait_object!(T);

#[derive(Clone)]
struct S1 {
    val: isize,
    nd: Box<dyn T>,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct S2 {
    val: isize,
}

impl T for S1 {}
impl T for S2 {}

fn main() {
    let x2 = S2 { val: 2 };
    let x1 = S1 {
        val: 1,
        nd: Box::new(x2),
    };
    let x1 = x1.clone();
}
```

There are some examples on [`dyn_clone` docs](https://docs.rs/dyn-clone/1.0.3/dyn_clone/) that may help more.

Comment: I would add that an `Rc` would be a viable alternative, if no actual clone but only another reference to the same underlying object is required. By the way, this is all perfectly answered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object).

Comment: @L.Riemer, indeed, `Rc` would be better in such cases. Yea, I see now, the question is duplicate. Should have searched for the same before answering. Will let this one stay though, first `rust` answer by me :p (pleasured).

Comment: Thank @Mihir , not me. He's the one who made the effort to hand-craft a solution for your exact usecase.

Comment: @Mihir,Thank you very much, it compiled successfully.