# How to fix `trait cannot be made into a trait object`?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
pub trait Service {}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Services {
    providers: std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<dyn Service>>
}
```

which gives this error:

```
the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `dyn Service`
```

I also tried changing `Service` to `pub trait Service: Clone {}` but it gave me a different error that the trait cannot be made into an object because it is not object_safe (because it requires `Self::Sized`.

playground - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eecca2b2bd82d4df4c34f44463594c58

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not gonna happened, if you look at the definition of Clone, it is required to Sized, but a trait object is not sized, you can't implement Clone for it.

you can wrap the provide in the Rc or Arc like this

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Services {
  providers: Arc<std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<dyn Service>>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Clone in the definition of the type that is enclosed in Box.

Something like this

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Service {}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Services<T>
    where
        T: Service, //<--------
        T: Clone //<----------- {
    providers: std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<T>>
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct A{}

impl Service for A {}

fn main()
{
    let mut v: HashMap<String, Box<A>> = HashMap::new();
    v.insert("test".to_string(), Box::new(A{}));
    
    let o = Services{providers: v };
    
    for (key, _) in o.providers.iter() {
        println!("key: {} ", key);
    }
}
```

The Sean version could be like this

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub trait Service {}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Services {
    providers: Arc<std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<dyn Service>>>
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct A{}
impl Service for A {}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct B{}
impl Service for B {}

fn main()
{
    let mut objects: HashMap<String, Box<dyn Service>> = HashMap::new();
    objects.insert("test".to_string(), Box::new(A{}));
    objects.insert("test2".to_string(), Box::new(B{}));
    
    let v = Arc::new(objects);
    let o = Services{providers: v};
    
    for (key, _) in o.providers.iter() {
        println!("key: {} ", key);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's quite different, you now make it static dispatch instead of dynamic dispatch

Comment: Hello, i think it was marked <dyn Service>, because her need is to define a generic type with trait Service and compiler require  to mark trait objects with an explicit `dyn`. But, now. Your also true. I dont know waht is her final goal.

Comment: it depend on how he gonna use the hashmap, if what he want is to put different types which impl the same trait in the map, that it has to be a trait-object

Comment: I want to put different types that impl the Service trait into the hashmap.

Comment: Hello @ferd, in this case this solution not work. You have to implement wath Sean has proposed.