# Can Clone be implemented for a trait object with finite lifetime (without using unsafe code)?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, trait-objects

### First things first: What am I trying to achieve?

I'm trying to use `Iterator::fold()` with an accumulator that itself is an `Iterator`, but in addition I need a clone of that iterator internally.

```
fn whatever<T,U,V,W>(some_iterator : T, other_cloneable_iterator_init : U) -> impl Iterator<Item=W>
where T: Iterator<Item=V>,
      U: Iterator<Item=W>+Clone
{
    some_iterator.fold(other_cloneable_iterator_init,|other_cloneable_iterator, value| {
        let computed_value =
            some_function_that_consumes_an_iterator(other_cloneable_iterator.clone(), value);
        other_iterator.filter(|other_value| some_function(computed_value, other_value))
    }
}
```

This of course does not work as written above, because the return type of the closure given to `fold` is not the same as the type of the initializer.

### Why did this problem lead to this question?

They do however have in common that they both implement the `Iterator<Item=W>+Clone` traits. This almost screams "erase the type by making it a trait object".

If it were just the `Iterator<Item=W>` trait, I'd do just that. However, the `Clone` trait is not object-safe. Searching for "clone boxed trait object" online yields various discussions, which all either [require `'static` lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object) on the trait object (what `Iterators` usually do not have), or using unsafe code (which I would like to avoid) like the [dyn-clone](https://github.com/dtolnay/dyn-clone) crate.

### The actual question:

So, if one wants to avoid using unsafe code, and does not have the luxury of getting `'static` lifetimes, how can one implement `Clone` for a boxed trait object?
I'm talking about code like the following, which has lifetime issues and does not compile:

```
trait Cu32Tst<'a> : Iterator<Item=u32>+'a {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Cu32Tst+'a>;
}
impl<'a, T : Iterator<Item=u32>+Clone+'a> Cu32Tst<'a> for T {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Cu32Tst+'a> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
impl<'a> Clone for Box<dyn Cu32Tst<'a>>{
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.box_clone()
    }
}
```

The reason I want `Clone` on the `Box` itself is that in order to use it as accumulator type, I must be able to create a new `Box<dyn IteratorTraitObject>` out of the output of the `Iterator::filter()` method, which is only `Clone` if the iterator it's called on is `Clone` (I'd then have to implement `Iterator` for the `Box` as well then, but that could just forward to the contained value).

Long story short: Can `Clone` be implemented for a trait object with finite lifetime, and if yes, how?

Comment: The code compiles with [this modification](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c436d3bdf2aee6e48c2a6dc9fbdb244). It's not obvious whether it will work for your use case because you didn't show exactly how you'd use it.

Comment: Strange, I was certain that I had tried that and it didn't work, but copy&pasting your changes into my source file made it compile. Could you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the code to implement `Box<dyn Cu32Tst<'a>>` rather than `Box<dyn Cu32Tst + 'a>`. The latter presumably implements `Cu32Tst<'static>`, which is not what you want for the blanket implementation of `Clone` for `Cu32Tst<'a>`. This compiles:

```
trait Cu32Tst<'a>: Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Cu32Tst<'a>>;
}

impl<'a, T: Iterator<Item = u32> + Clone + 'a> Cu32Tst<'a> for T {
    fn box_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn Cu32Tst<'a>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl<'a> Clone for Box<dyn Cu32Tst<'a>> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.as_ref().box_clone()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec20e41c64f5f5a2e08590aec420fd86)

Note that the `Clone` implementation invokes `box_clone()` using `self.as_ref().box_clone()`. This is because the blanket impl of `Cu32Tst` matches against the `Box<dyn Cu32Tst>` as it's both `Clone` and `Iterator`, so the box itself gets a `box_clone()` method. As a result, `self.box_clone()` would compile, but would cause infinite recursion.