# How to clone a boxed trait Error ( Box<dyn Error> )?

Tags: rust, future

I am using using clonable futures using the shared() method on a future that returns `Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>`. However, Clone is not implemented for dyn Error. I tried creating my own custom error type (`CustomError`) that wraps `Box<dyn Error>` instead and tried to implement Clone on that but it still doesn't work. I feel like I am missing something trivial here.

Here's what I tried

```
use std::error::Error;  

#[derive(Debug)]  
pub struct CustomError(pub Box<dyn Error>);  

impl Clone for CustomError{  
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {  
        CustomError(Box::*new*(self.0.clone())) // doesn't work due to unsatisfied trait bounds, what else can I do?
    }  
}
```

Here's the error I get if I try to use `Box<dyn Error>` as my return type when calling shared() on the future. Any solutions to this?

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(dyn StdError + 'static): Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/scrapers/form_4_xml_scraper.rs:56:52
   |
56 |             let document_fut = self.scrape(filing).shared();
   |                                                    ^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `(dyn StdError + 'static)`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)>`
   = note: 1 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `std::result::Result<(Filing, Form4XMLDocument), Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering, I used `Arc` instead of `Box` and it worked perfectly.