# How to store Rust closures that use enclosing state

Tags: rust, closures

I've found two ways to return closures from functions that use enclosing state:

```rust
fn closure_try(t: u64) -> Box<dyn Fn(u64) -> u64> {
    let f = |x: u64| x + t;
    return Box::new(f);
}

fn closure_try2(t: u64) -> impl Fn(u64) -> u64 {
    let f = move |x: u64| x + t.clone();
    return f;
}
```

Now, I need to store the output object into a struct and also be able to clone it.

Unfortunately, in the second instance, trait `impl` objects cannot be in struct position.

```rust
struct A {
    b: impl Fn(u64) -> u64
}
```

This fails with: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and method return types.

In the first example, the boxed dynamic trait object cannot be copied or cloned.

```rust
fn duplicate(f: Box<dyn Fn(u64) -> u64>) -> Box<dyn Fn(u64) -> u64> {
    f.clone()
}
```

This fails with the error "doesn't satisfy `dyn Fn(u64) -> u64: Clone`"

What would be an idiomatic way to create a store of closures where:

- Closures can be duplicated
- Each closure can capture some enclosing state

One option I'm considering is to have these functions return a closure that return the closure, but this seems problematic.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "in the second instance, trait `impl` objects cannot be in struct position". Can you show us some code that you have tried to "store the output object" and the corresponding error message?

Comment: @Jmb The struct position language is what is used in rustc compiler issues. I've provided a code example of how to trigger the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom method to clone `Box<dyn Trait>`, see [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object):

```rust
trait ClonableFn: Fn(u64) -> u64 {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableFn>;
}
impl Clone for Box<dyn ClonableFn> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        <dyn ClonableFn>::clone_box(&**self)
    }
}
impl<T> ClonableFn for T
where
    T: 'static + Fn(u64) -> u64 + Clone,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableFn> {
        Box::new(T::clone(self))
    }
}

fn closure_try(t: u64) -> Box<dyn ClonableFn> {
    let f = move |x: u64| x + t;
    Box::new(f)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4562c859ccf753998eaa02fb3a25126c).

Or, you can use the unstable feature [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html) to name the return type of the second method:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

type ClosureType = impl Fn(u64) -> u64 + Clone;
fn closure_try(t: u64) -> ClosureType {
    move |x: u64| x + t
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c60fba64b79abded8c14aab2cd3c3daf)

The latter approach is more performant, but nightly-only as of today.

Comment: Thanks this is great! I'm following the latter approach but couldn't get it to work to create an array of closures. Added a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689947/cannot-find-defining-use-when-declaring-closure-in-a-struct.