# Conflicting defining use when declaring closure in a struct

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to create a struct that holds multiple copyable closures.

```rust
type ClosureType = impl Fn(u64) -> u64 + Clone;


fn closure_try(t: u64) -> ClosureType {
    move |x: u64| x + t
}
fn closure_try_other(u: u64) -> ClosureType {
    move |x: u64| x - u
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Wrapper {
    pub h: Vec<ClosureType>
}
trait Tr: Clone {
    fn dup(s: Self) -> (Self, Self);
}
impl Tr for Wrapper {
    fn dup(c: Self) -> (Self, Self) {
        (c.clone(), c)
    }
}
```

However this code fails with the error for `ClosureType`:

```
rustc: concrete type differs from previous defining opaque type use
```

Does it mean that this approach cannot be used to store multiple different closures?

Comment: Is this all the code? When using TAIT (type alias impl trait, `type T = impl ...`), the compiler should bind it to some concrete type. There should be a function that returns this type, a variable with this type or something like that.

Comment: I just added some more usage code. If I use 2 different functions, I get a usage conflict. Does this mean that this approach cannot be used to store multiple different closures in one vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type T = impl Trait` is only a way to name the opaque type. It is an *existential type*, meaning it has one and only one concrete definition. `ClosureType` is some unnamable type, but it cannot be *two distinct* types, for the same reason [you cannot return two different types from a function that returns `impl Trait`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001592/why-can-impl-trait-not-be-used-to-return-multiple-conditional-types).

If you need multiple types for the `Vec`, i.e. a *heterogeneous* collection, you have to use dynamic dispath, i.e. `dyn Trait`.