# How to create a vector based on an `&[Box<dyn CustomTrait>]`?

Tags: rust

I have a custom trait that I use as the element type in a slice:

```rs
pub trait IConstraint {
  // members here
}

pub struct Scenario<'a> {
  pub constraints: &'a [Box<dyn IConstraint>]
}
```

I would like to offer an `add_constraint` method that does a copy-on-write of the slice. Something like this:

```rs
impl<'a> Scenario<'a> {
    pub fn add_constraint(&mut self, constraint: Box<dyn IConstraint<TNodeState>>) {
        let mut constraints: Vec<Box<dyn IConstraint<TNodeState>>> = Vec::new();
        constraints.copy_from_slice(self.constraints);
        constraints.push(constraint);
        self.constraints = &constraints;
    }
}
```

The problem is I get this error:

> the trait bound `Box<dyn IConstraint<TNodeState>>: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
> the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `Box<dyn IConstraint<TNodeState>>`

Ok, so the `Box<T>` doesn't implement the `Copy` trait. Fair enough. But how do I address that? Ideally, I'd reuse the boxes or at least the constraints because they are immutable. But if I can't do that due to rust ownership rules, how can I implement the `Copy` trait on a box type? I've tried various ways and they all produce errors.

This attempt produces "Copy not allowed on types with destructors":

```rs
impl<TNodeState> Copy for Box<dyn IConstraint<TNodeState>> {
}
```

What about Clone? I can switch to `constraints.clone_from_slice(self.constraints);`, but then implementing the `Clone` trait on `IConstraint` produces a bunch of "IConstraint cannot be made into an object" errors.

Even if I could get box to be cloneable, then of course I get the anticipated borrow lifetime flaw from my `add_constraint` method:

> borrowed value does not live long enough

So do I have to throw out my `add_constraint` function idea altogether and force the owner of my struct to manually copy it? Given my actual struct contains 3 fields, that gets tedious as the owner now has to deconstruct the fields into locals in order to drop the immutable borrow, allowing the original vector to be mutated:

```rs
fn add_remove_constraint() {
    let mut scenario = Scenario::<&str, bool, 3_usize>::new(&["A", "B", "C"]);
    let mut constraints: Vec<Box<dyn IConstraint<bool>>> = Vec::new();
    constraints.push(Box::new(SelectionCountConstraint {
        nodes: [1, 2],
        min: 1,
        max: 2,
    }));
    scenario = Scenario {
        constraints: &constraints,
        ..scenario
    };

    assert_eq!(1, scenario.get_constraints().len());
    let nodes = scenario.nodes;
    let selection_state = scenario.selection_state;
    constraints.pop();
    scenario = Scenario {
        constraints: &constraints,
        nodes,
        selection_state,
    };
    assert_eq!(0, scenario.get_constraints().len());
}
```

Comment: If you want shared ownership, you probably should reach out for `Rc<T>`

Comment: your `add_constrain` method will never work as you are referencing something that is being created in the same function.

Comment: Nitpick: Hungarian notation (`TParam`, `IInterface`) is not used with Rust usually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it all wrong. As said in the comments, your `add_constraint` will never work, because you are referencing something you create in the same function in the first place (which will be dropped after the function scope expires).

You should own a container over those `IConstraint` trait, but inside you should have an `&dyn IConstraint` or `Box<dyn IConstraint>`.

Adding an item to them is trivial in that case:

```rust
pub trait IConstraint {
  // members here
}

pub struct Scenario<'a> {
  pub constraints: Vec<&'a dyn IConstraint>
}

impl<'a> Scenario<'a> {
    pub fn add_constraint(&mut self, constraint: &'a dyn IConstraint) {
        self.constraints.push(constraint);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bcb2eed2ba67e43bf4725771722215cb)

This should solve your problem since **references are `Copy`**.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I'm _very_ new to rust so I accept the "you got it all wrong" ruling. :)
> You should own a container over those IConstraint trait
Doesn't that mean that copies of `Scenario` will have to clone the vector? I'm trying to avoid that. I'm not sure how that would even work given `dyn trait` doesn't seem to like to be cloneable.

Comment: Ah, maybe your bolded ending comment explains it: a `Vec<T>` copies by ref, so no cloning is necessary in that case? I'll try that out.

Comment: I do find that cloning my Scenario requires that I call `constraints.clone()`. Is that going to be a fast reference copy or will it copy the contents into a new array? I'm hoping for a fast reference copy.

Comment: @AndrewArnott it will clone just the references. You would have a new vector with references

Comment: I don't want a new vector though. That's another heap allocation and copy of a potentially long vector, even if the elements of the vector are themselves just references. I think I'll try separating the most mutable state (the `nodes` field) from the rest of the fields so that I can do as you suggest but without incurring the shallow copy cost.