# Struggling with Clone on Trait

Tags: rust

Somewhat new to Trait implementation/usage:

If I declare a trait thus:

```rust
pub trait A: Debug + Clone {
    fn as_base58_string(&self) -> String;
    fn as_bytes(&self) -> [u8; 32];
}
```

With a concrete implementation:

```rust
    impl A for P {
        fn as_base58_string(&self) -> String {
            self.to_base58_string()
        }

        fn as_bytes(&self) -> [u8; 32] {
            self.to_bytes()
        }
    }
```

And have a function like:

```rust
pub fn print_akey(akey: &dyn A) {
    println!("A{:?}", akey);
}
```

I am getting this error

```bash
the trait `A` cannot be made into an object`A` cannot be made into an object
```

Even though the concrete type `P` is cloneable?

If I remove `Clone` from the trait declaration the warning goes away/

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clone` is not [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). That means you cannot create a `dyn Clone`, and thus you cannot create `dyn Trait` for any `Trait` that has `Clone` as a supertrait.

The reason for that is that `Clone::clone()` returns `Self`, and one of the rules for object safe traits is that they must never mention the `Self` type (outside of `&self` or `&mut self`).

If you want to clone a trait object (`dyn Trait`), see [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object).