# Type for cloneable dynamic closure?

Tags: rust

I have a Rust struct containing a number of callback functions. Due to the way the struct is used, I'm modeling the callbacks as dynamic closures, like this:

```
struct Callbacks {
    callback_a: Box<dyn Fn() -> i32>,
    callback_b: Box<dyn Fn() -> u64>,
    callback_c: Box<dyn Fn() -> i8>,
}
```

Now I want to derive `Clone` for my struct. For this to work, each of the callbacks needs to be cloneable, too.

I tried expressing this as `Box<dyn (Fn() -> i32) + Clone>`, but that syntax doesn't seem to be valid Rust.

How can I express the type of a cloneable dynamic closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `Box<dyn (Fn() -> i32) + Clone>` is valid Rust syntax (although those paranthesis are unnecessary – `Box<dyn Fn() -> i32 + Clone>` would work, too). However, you now have two trait bounds in your dyn trait, and Rust doesn't like that:

```
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
 --> src/lib.rs:2:41
  |
2 |     callback_a: Box<dyn (Fn() -> i32) + Clone>,
  |                         -------------   ^^^^^ additional non-auto trait
  |                         |
  |                         first non-auto trait
  |
  = help: consider creating a new trait with all of these as supertraits and using that trait here instead: `trait NewTrait: Fn<()> + Clone {}`
  = note: auto-traits like `Send` and `Sync` are traits that have special properties; for more information on them, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#auto-traits>
```

Like the message says, you could create new traits that have the wanted traits as supertraits:

```
trait CloneableI32Closure: Fn() -> i32 + Clone {}

struct Callbacks {
    callback_a: Box<dyn CloneableI32Closure>,
    // removed other callbacks for simplicity
}
```

But that does not work either:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `CloneableI32Closure` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/lib.rs:4:21
  |
4 |     callback_a: Box<dyn CloneableI32Closure>,
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `CloneableI32Closure` cannot be made into an object
  |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
 --> src/lib.rs:1:42
  |
1 | trait CloneableI32Closure: Fn() -> i32 + Clone {}
  |       -------------------                ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
  |       |
  |       this trait cannot be made into an object...
```

`Clone` is not object safe, so our new trait isn't either. [There are workarounds for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353928/4674154), however, in this case, it might be easier to just use `Rc` instead of `Box`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Callbacks {
    callback_a: Rc<dyn Fn() -> i32>,
    callback_b: Rc<dyn Fn() -> u64>,
    callback_c: Rc<dyn Fn() -> i8>,
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d9e54c83d8eafe3d8092ff4c2bb44845)

This will have a slight overhead for counting the references, however, the overhead for dynamically dispatching the dyn trait is assumably considerably higher – if performance is critical, a generic struct would probably be better suited.