# How to implement Clone on a struct that contains dyn Iterator in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, clone

I have the following struct in Rust:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct EquationIterator<F> {
    counter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>,
    formula: Arc<dyn Fn(usize) -> Equation<F>>,
}
```

I had to use an `Arc` to wrap the closure otherwise I couldn't implement `Clone` on the struct. Even with this, I still cannot derive `Clone` because the compiler is complaining about the `dyn Iterator` not implementing `Clone`.

I've tried implementing `Clone` manually but no luck either. Any idea?

To add more colors, this structure is an iterator that goes through some arbitrary range (e.g. `counter = [2, 5, 9]`) and calls some closure with the current counter value as argument

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fb31441d9007d51c050bdd9e8f2d5c7

Comment: Why aren't you using generics?

Comment: in this case, I want to be able to have vectors of EquationIterators that don't have the same type of iterators. For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1a51e067886abdfdd57b6a420f82855

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30353462/6274355 It's slightly different because you don't own the `Iterator` trait but the same restriction applies.

Comment: One big problem you have is that `Clone` is not object safe. So you need your own version of `Clone` that returns a boxed trait object instead of `Self`.

Comment: As a side note, you don't want to `derive` here because this adds the bound `F: Clone` which is not actually required (no `F` need be cloned). You will probably want to implement `Clone` manually.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Clone` isn't [object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) (it would return the actual type, not `Box<dyn Clone>`), you need a workaround. You can almost use the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30353462/6274355), except because you don't own the `Iterator` trait, you need to make a new trait. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc729f05ffac1ae000da2cdc66554438)

```rs
trait ClonableIterator: Iterator {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableIterator<Item = Self::Item>>;
}

impl<T, I> ClonableIterator for T
where
    T: Iterator<Item = I> + Clone + 'static,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableIterator<Item = I>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

Then you can store a trait object of this trait in your struct.

```rs
counter: Box<dyn ClonableIterator<Item = usize>>
```

And you can implement `Clone` for your struct using `clone_box`.

```rs
impl<F> Clone for EquationIterator<F> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        EquationIterator {
            counter: self.counter.clone_box(),
            formula: self.formula.clone(),
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do this for the `Fn` trait, which I've upgraded to `FnMut` since it is now owned exclusively.

```rs
trait ClonableFnMut<T, O>: FnMut(T) -> O {
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<T, O>>;
}

impl<F, T, O> ClonableFnMut<T, O> for F
where
    F: FnMut(T) -> O + Clone + 'static,
{
    fn clone_box(&self) -> Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<T, O>> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
```

And then you can add it to the struct.

```rs
formula: Box<dyn ClonableFnMut<usize, F>>
```

And change your `Clone` implementation.

```rs
formula: self.formula.clone_box()
```

I couldn't quite get this to work with [dyn-clone](https://docs.rs/dyn-clone), but there might be a way.

Note that you would need to implement `Clone` manually anyway because the derive would make it conditional on `F` being `Clone`, which isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an implementor of `Iterator` is not clonable. You need to specify to the compiler that only types that implement `Clone` and `Interator` are allowed.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct EquationIterator<F, I: Iterator<Item = usize> + Clone> {
    counter: Box<I>,
    formula: Arc<dyn Fn(usize) -> F>,
}

fn main() {

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bbd9841b536e34e9de4662a0da233d52)