# Blanket `impl Trait1` for all types which `impl Trait2` and functions which return `impl Trait2`

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I want to implement `HasChildren` for all types which implement `Element` and for all functions which return `impl Element`.

My case use is that I have a `Vec<Box<dyn HasChildren>>` in which I want to be able to store both types which implement `Element` and functions which return `impl Element`.

Worth noting that my wider use case requires using trait objects, so a solution eg using enums is not possible.

```rust
trait Element {}

trait HasChildren {}

impl<T: 'static + Element + Clone> HasChildren for T {}

// conflicting implementation
impl<F, E: Element> HasChildren for F where F: FnMut() -> E {}

// Types which I would like to use as HasChildren trait objects
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo {}
impl Element for Foo {}

fn get_element() -> impl Element {
    Foo {}
}

// My use case - storing both the above types in a Vector
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<Box<dyn HasChildren>> = Vec::new();
    data.push(Box::new(Foo {}));
    data.push(Box::new(get_element));
}
```

Comment: Nothing prevents structs **outside** of your crate to implement both `FnMut` and `Element`. In that case, Rust doesn't know which implementation to pick. That's why those two blanket impl's collide.

Comment: Yes my understanding is that the problem is I cannot have two blanket implementations for a Trait. Are there any work around for my use case? In my head, types which implement Element and functions which return `impl Element` seem sufficiently distinct but I can't think how to achieve this in Rust.

Comment: *"My case use is that I have a `Vec<Box<dyn HasChildren>>` in which I want to be able to store both types which implement Element and functions which return impl Element"* - is using a newtype wrapper an option for you? Apart of that (and using enums, obviously), I don't see another way to achieve that.

Comment: You can also impl it for `fn() -> Element` (fn pointers, not any `FnMut`), although this forbids capturing closures and requires a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html):

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

trait Element {}

trait HasChildren {}

// Newtype wrapper for `FnMut() -> E`
struct ElementFn<F: FnMut() -> E, E: Element>(F);
impl<F: FnMut() -> E, E: Element> Deref for ElementFn<F, E> {
    type Target = F;

    fn deref(&self) -> &F {
        &self.0
    }
}
impl<F: FnMut() -> E, E: Element> DerefMut for ElementFn<F, E> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut F {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

// conflicting implementation
impl<T: Element + Clone> HasChildren for T {}
impl<F: FnMut() -> E, E: Element> HasChildren for ElementFn<F, E> {}

// Types which I would like to use as HasChildren trait objects
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo {}
impl Element for Foo {}

fn get_element() -> impl Element {
    Foo {}
}

// My use case - storing both the above types in a Vector
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<Box<dyn HasChildren>> = Vec::new();
    data.push(Box::new(Foo {}));
    data.push(Box::new(ElementFn(get_element)));
}
```

Comment: I think this approach will work for me, thank you so much. I was overzealous with my *minimal* reproducible example and didn't include the fact that I impl Clone on HasChildren using this pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353928/7092900 so I am currently adding 'static and Clone everywhere to try and make things work! I will make another question if I can't get it to work. Thanks again.