# Borrow in filter closure does not live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

When I try to compile this code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a06dc16f4149afd0c31d960b05fa958b&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    let iter = "abc123".chars().filter(&|&c: &char| c.is_digit(10));
    match iter.clone().take(3).count() {
        3 => println!("{}", iter.collect::<String>()),
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> test.rs:2:41
  |
2 |     let iter = "abc123".chars().filter(&|c: &char| c.is_digit(10));
  |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value only lives until here
  |                                         |
  |                                         temporary value created here
...
7 | }
  | - temporary value needs to live until here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

I understand that the error is helpfully telling me to declare the closure in the line above with `let f = &|c: &char| c.is_digit(10);` ([working code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20f%20%3D%20%26%7Cc%3A%20%26char%7C%20c.is_digit(10)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20iter%20%3D%20%22abc123%22.chars().filter(f)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20iter.clone().take(3).count()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20iter.collect%3A%3A%3CString%3E())%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)), but why exactly is this necessary?

I'm also not sure why the closure has to contain two references - `&|c: &char|`. Doesn't `"abc123".chars()` simply create an iterator of chars?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31374051/155423; near duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28776630/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23969191/155423, [working code](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=feb39ad6c2bd1641dcf463b65d560986&version=stable); TL;DR: you probably want to use `by_ref`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I guess what I was trying to ask is how to clone an Iterator (before I got confused by the error message). So how would I do [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a8f4f33423f100f857ffe2ce4f0263a8&version=stable&backtrace=0) for example (I know this isn't the best way to do it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but why exactly is this necessary?

I don't really know how to explain it much better than the error messages:

> ```
> temporary value only lives until here
> temporary value created here
> ```

You are creating a temporary value (the closure itself) in a statement and then taking a reference to it. When the statement ends, the value is destroyed — nothing owns it! The problem is that the code tries to keep the *reference* to the now-destroyed value. If the compiler allowed this, then when it went to use that reference, who knows what random data would be accessed.

> the closure has to contain two references

Well, it doesn't *have* to. `filter(|c| c.is_digit(10))` works just fine; type inference allows `c` to be automatically typed as `&char`. The `&c` only pattern-matches and automatically dereferences the value. That's redundant because method calls [automatically dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423).

The bigger issue is that the code is attempting to clone an iterator containing a closure, which you cannot do ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27883509/155423), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28011803/155423), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39803231/155423), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21933892/155423) (goodness, people refuse to search before asking a question)). The clever way that you've chosen to work around this is by cloning a *reference* to a closure, which is fine.

The problem loops back to taking a reference to something that is destroyed at the end of the statement.

---

**If** the goal is to ignore all non-digits, skip over the first 3 digits and then collect the rest of the digits, you can use [`Iterator::skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip):

```
let iter = "abc123".chars().filter(|c| c.is_digit(10));
let together: String = iter.skip(3).collect();
println!("{}", together);
```

**If** the goal is to take only the first 3 digits if and only if there were three digits, then I might always collect those digits, and check to see if that was the end:

```
let mut iter = "abc123".chars().filter(|c| c.is_digit(10));
let together: String = iter.by_ref().take(3).collect();

if iter.next().is_none() {
    println!("{}", together);
}
```

This uses [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref). Instead of *consuming* the iterator, `by_ref` creates a mutable reference to it. Mutable references to iterators *also* implement `Iterator`, so calling `take` and `collect` work fine. When those are done, however, `iter` remains valid.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, what happened is I originally had something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=080f87f21823940bb52e92bc55a1299c&version=stable&backtrace=0), but then I ended up with the `&|c: &char|` trying to appease the compiler. This is just me trying to get to an MCVE, I know this isn't the best way to do it.

This is really enlightening though!